# Instead of quadratic ROI , I need an ellipse ROI in java(eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, imagej, roi

My object is elliptical, and so I need an ellipse ROI.
for Quadratic I know that I can change the range of width and height, but I have no idea how can I choose the ellipse [like the bellow pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMeaE.jpg) region in eclipse.

Comment: What GUI system are you asking about (JavaFX, SWT, Swing, Android, .....)?

Comment: @greg-449 ImageJ

Comment: @greg-449 can this class be the answer? https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/gui/EllipseRoi.html

Comment: I don't know anything about ImageJ.

Comment: This question is better asked on the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/).

Comment: @JanEglinger thanks for introducing this forum to me..